# Function return sys_refcursor

Tags: database, oracle, function, plsql, oracle10g

I have a question regarding sys_refcursor.

A sys_refcursor can only be used with a select statement or can this be used like the following. I would like the function to return sys_refcursor.

**p_cursor is defined as sys_refcursor**

```
FOR i IN c
    LOOP
        IF (p_start_date BETWEEN i.start_date AND i.end_date)
            OR (p_end_date BETWEEN i.start_date AND i.end_date)
        THEN
            p_cursor := i.product_no;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
```

Comment: thats not a cursor, its a single value.  What are you looking for, to return a list of product numbers?

Comment: @tbone I would like to know whether to assign product_no and another column to p_cursor if I am not using SQL statement.

Comment: @tbone If the condition satisfy then I would like to assign list of product numbers. Thanks

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean by - "assign another column to a sys_refcursor"? From last I checked you cannot assign anything to a `sys_refcursor` you can either define a strong or a weak refcursor. You can also fetch from a cursor (refcursor) into an array, collection, rowtype etc. etc. Quick [example](http://www.oradev.com/ref_cursor.jsp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two ways of doing this depending on what you want.

**First**
If you always want to have the column in your cursor, and depending on that condition, to assign a value to the column or not. You can do the following

Code:

```
OPEN p_cursor FOR   
SELECT i.columna1, i.columna2,
       (SELECT i.product_no
          FROM dual
         WHERE (p_start_date BETWEEN i.start_date AND i.end_date)
            OR (p_end_date BETWEEN i.start_date AND i.end_date)
        ) as product_no
FROM table_name i
```

**Second**
If you want sometimes to have the column and sometimes you just dont. You can dinamically create the query in a `varchar` variable and then assign that query to the cursor.

Code:

```
DECLARE
  var VARCHAR2(200);  
BEGIN

  var := 'select * from dual';

  open p_cursor for var;

END;
```